# Где найти украинский словарь?

Tags: словарь, поиск-данных

Может у кого-то есть база украинских слов или знаете API, с которого можно брать случайные слова? Мне нужна база именно существительных. Никак не могу найти

Comment: Закрывшие вопрос, вы точно понимаете, что делаете? Вопрос был закрыт предвзято. На него можно дать объективный ответ (что я и сделал). Если бы в вопросе звучал русский язык или английский - подозреваю, что даже не возникло бы подобных вопросов.

Comment: @KoVadim - На stackoverflow не приветствуются темы с поиском библиотек, софта и т. п. Думаю, на en.so такой вопрос точно закрыли бы. Но у нас правила в этом отношении мягче. Наверное, можно оставить.

Comment: Поддерживаю, вопрос интересный на самом деле

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться словарями от [GNU Aspell](https://github.com/arysin/spell-uk/tree/master/src/Dictionary). Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/arysin/spell-uk/tree/master/src/Dictionary), а именно в [base.lst](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arysin/spell-uk/master/src/Dictionary/base.lst).

Там правда разные слова, не только существительные, но там есть метаинформация:)

Comment: о, спасибо вам огромное) изучу источники

Comment: вот интересно, минусуют ответ те же, кто и вопрос минусует?

Comment: не подскажете, пожалуйста, как будет эффективнее спарсить base.lst? по regex?

Comment: я бы просто  grep'оп прошелся и отфильтровал. Вот здесь нашел заметно лучше словарик - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/master/data/dict/base.lst  фильтр можно легко по `grep '/n' base.lst | grep -o '.*/'`

Comment: окей, спасибо )